# large size HTML5 app

Tags: android, html, cordova, package, large-data

I'm developing an **HTML5 application** having lots of **animations** and logic running behind it.
**Large number** of **images** and **audio files** are used in the application to achieve better UI and UX.
I think when I complete this app, It'll be of more than **250 mb** in size.
For the web, it wont be any issue since I divided each every modules to several of html pages.
But what if I need to **package** it with **phoneGap** for **Android Tab** and **iPad**.
Is it possible package an app with large size?

Is there any other method to package it with smaller size?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Cordova app here that is well over 1GB. As long as you stay within other limits like the 2GB maximum for the app store, size shouldn't be a problem.

You will need to build locally of course - PhoneGap Build has a hard file size limit, and cloud build services are generally impractical for anything that large.

If possible, set up your app so that it can easily be packaged without most of the media for debugging - the full version takes forever to build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Clarkson. Is it like a normal phoneGap - packaging or I need to do some other stuffs to package it? Can you share any helpful links?